# The subscription mails are not getting. How to get subscription mail

Tags: subscription, dspace

The subscription mails are not getting from our DSpace repository... All other mails are getting (like mail to admin for approve a submitted item, mail when an item submitted is get approved, etc.)..
How to get subscription mail  ??

Answer (score 0):

Sending subscription notices requires a cron job or scheduled tasks (for Windows OS) for it to work. The command for that is: `[dspace]\bin\dspace sub-daily`. Then you should set a schedule for it to run (the recommended frequency is daily).